# How can I calculate the rendered height of an HTML table, from within JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, rendering

When the window is resized, I need to know how big the table is, so I can dynamically fit everything else nicely in-between. The table height is solely dependant on the contents, which are loaded dynamically. How do you calculate the rendered height of the table in JavaScript?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`element.offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.offsetHeight) for this.

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
alert(table.offsetHeight);
```